# Convert X509_STORE_load_locations() call to load data from Memory

Tags: c, openssl

How can I convert the code below to load the file "cabundle.pem" from memory? The code is used in certificate verification ([Source](http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certverify.htm))

```
    const char ca_bundlestr[] = "./cabundle.pem";
    ret = X509_STORE_load_locations(store, ca_bundlestr, NULL);`
```

So what I currently did is put the cabundle.pem in string array and then add the cert to the store but it doesnt work since what I think I need to do is add it to the store using X509_STORE_CTX_trusted_stack but I do not know how to use STACK_OF(X509) I tried searching but I cant find anything.

```
    const char ca_bundle[] = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
    "MIIImDCCCD2gAwIBAgIRAMch/W0685E2zrArUB/79kUwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwgZIx\n"
    "MIIImDCCC...............................................AwIwgZIx\n"
    "CzAJBgNVB..........................................0ZXIxEDAOBgNV\n"
    "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

    BIO *bio;
    X509 *cert;

    bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO_puts(bio, ca_bundle);
    cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    X509_STORE_add_cert(store, cert);
```

So how can I load my string array `ca_bundle` into a STACK_OF(X509) variable? Or if there is another way to do this please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked too early. I just found the answer to my question. Since the cabundle.pem contains more than 1 certificate you need to do it in a loop and read the next certificate then add it again to the store. You do not need the `X509_STORE_CTX_trusted_stack` since adding all the certificates to the store acts the same way as calling `X509_STORE_load_locations`

```
while (cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
    X509_STORE_add_cert(store, cert);
}
```